# MYSQL Governor and event_scheduler working together?

Tags: mysql, cpu-usage

I am wondering if anyone knows if MYSQL Governor will help reduce the CPU (etc) usage for use of event_scheduler

It is a dangerous setting to put on if I am not sure that Governor will put limits to this.

Thanks!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with sw development, this is pure operations stuff. DBAs or sysadmin would be in a lot better position to answer your question, than sw developers.

Comment: Of course, thanks!